# How to restrict InterpolatingFunction to a smaller domain?

Tags: interpolation

How can I reduce the domain of an `InterpolatingFunction`?

For example, consider `if = FunctionInterpolation[x^2, {x, 0, 3}]`. Is it possible to define `if2` as the restriction of `if` to `{x,1,2}`? Not only should the domain change, but `if2` should not contain the information of `if` on $[0,1]$ and $[2,3]$. I've noticed the package `InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy` but I don't know what methods would be useful here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do:

```
FunctionInterpolation[if[x], {x, 1, 2}]
```

which will actually sample the interpolation function and generate a new one.

Alternately you can extract the data and use `Interpolation`

```
Interpolation[
   Select[ Transpose[{#[[3, 1]], Flatten[#[[4]]]}] , 
    1 <= #[[1]] <= 2 &]] &@if
```

This second method may not exactly match your desired domain boundaries unless they happened to be sample points on the original interpolation.

In both cases the result will not be *precisely* the same as the original interpolation.

yet another thing you can do, which seems a bit of a hack. Looking at the `FullForm` of `InterpolatingFunction` you see the first argument is the domain, so if you do:

```
if[[1]] = {{1, 2}}
```

you will get a warning if you go out of the new bounds (but get the same result as the original)

Edit: this will use the derivatives from the first interpolation in the second:

```
data = Select[Transpose[{#[[3, 1]], Flatten[#[[4]]]}], 
                 1 <= #[[1]] <= 2 &] &@if;
Interpolation[{{#[[1]]}, #[[2]], D[if[x], x] /. x -> #[[1]]} & /@ data]
```

Comment: Do you know how to control the number of points with `FunctionInterpolation`? When I try it on actual interpolating functions, it clearly reduces the quality of the original `if`.

Comment: You can do `Interpolation[Table[f[x],..]]` to sample as many points as you like (you do loose adaptive refinement that way though)

Comment: Just for illustration purpose of my previous comment: http://imgur.com/a/9trUF.

Comment: see edit for a refinement, but really if you need it to stay precisely the same you should just use the original.

Comment: @anderstood Note that `FunctionInterpolation` produces a different method interpolation than `NDSolve`.

Comment: I still have an issue with this: I'd like to keep the exact same interpolating function, so I use something of the type `if[[1]] = {{1, 2}}`. However I store the whole function (typically defined on a 20 times larger interval) which is really suboptimal. Do you think it's possible to chop oup the points out of something like `{{0.9,2.1}}`, i.e. keep the same interpolation points in the interval of interest, and crop most of the unused parts?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe the following meets your desiderata:

```
if2[x_ /; 1 <= x <= 2] = if[x];

if2[0.9]
(* if2[0.9] *)

if2[1.1]
(* 1.21 *)
```