# Understanding the structure of an InterpolatingFunction

Tags: interpolation, implementation-details

```
FunctionInterpolation[x^2, {x, 0, 9}] // InputForm
```

returns:

```
InterpolatingFunction[
  {{0., 9.}},
  {5, 3, 0, {13}, {4}, 0, 0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, False}, 
  {{0., 0.75, 1.5, 2.25, 3., 3.75, 4.5, 5.25, 6., 6.75, 7.5, 8.25, 9.}}, 
  {{0.}, {0.5625}, {2.25}, {5.0625}, {9.}, {14.0625}, {20.25}, {27.5625}, {36.}, 
       {45.5625}, {56.25}, {68.0625}, {81.}},
  {Automatic}]
```

Some of the lists can easily be understood: first line is the `Domain`, third line is the list of x coordinates of the interpolating points, fourth line is the list of their y coordinates (why in `List` of `List`?).

I'd like to understand more precisely the structure to modify it manually (more precisely, I'd like to define an interpolating function by "cropping" the `InterpolatingFunction` on a smaller domain, without changing the points in the interval of interest--this last condition was not included in my previous question [How to restrict InterpolatingFunction to a smaller domain?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/130040/how-to-restrict-interpolatingfunction-to-a-smaller-domain)).

This would allow me to see for example what's wrong in the following, which I made from another huge interpolating function but is not recognized as a packed `InterpolatingFunction` (it does not return the nice form).

```
InterpolatingFunction[{{-14.7299, -14.6565}}, {5, 7, 1, {3}, {4}, 0, 
  0, 0, 0, Automatic, {}, {}, 
  False}, {{-211.618, -211.576, -211.481}}, \
 {Developer`PackedArrayForm, {0, 2, 4}, {20.9957, 0.784718, 21.0292, 
   0.782668, 21.1027, 0.777747}}, {Automatic}]
```

Comment: Have you seen http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4 (but it's not the full story - there are many types of IFs)

Comment: @MichaelE2 No I had not, thank you. I'll read it and either answer, delete or edit my question.

Comment: BTW, if you change `{0,2,4}` to `{0, 2, 4, 6}`, the last example works. It's a list of indices of where to split the array of values that follows it. The indices need to start with `0` and end with the length of the array.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you!! That was my problem; I had tried with $n+1$ elements but had not started with 0. I wrapped all that in a `cropInterpolatingFunction` which I will share here soon.

Comment: Glad it was so easy. I think I described the parts of a ``Developer`PackedArrayForm`` IF in a little more detail [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/98349/4999).  (Well, at least there's a little comment for more of the pieces.)

Comment: beware if you crop the data you end up changing the resulting interpolation.  you need to keep a few points past the end of your domain (depending on the order of the interpolation)

Comment: The structure of `InterpolatingFunction` is explained here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you. Michael E2 had mentioned this link above. I just marked the question as duplicate.